# PHPMailer SMTP SSL Error

Tags: php, phpmailer

Below is my code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "test@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('test@company.com', 'First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('test@yahoo.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('test@yahoo.com', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML('test');

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('phpmailer.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

but it displays this error:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP oo3sm681775pdb.26 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [124.13.146.153]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
( ! ) Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support
 SSL/crypto in C:\wamp\www\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 344

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  253800  {main}( )   ..\ibdex1.php:0
2   0.0061  944248  PHPMailer->send( )  ..\ibdex1.php:52
3   0.0069  962000  PHPMailer->postSend( )  ..\class.phpmailer.php:970
4   0.0069  962368  PHPMailer->smtpSend( )  ..\class.phpmailer.php:1062
5   0.0069  963320  PHPMailer->smtpConnect( )   ..\class.phpmailer.php:1218
6   0.8391  1164280 SMTP->startTLS( )   ..\class.phpmailer.php:1343
7   1.0490  1164576 stream_socket_enable_crypto ( ) ..\class.smtp.php:344

CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT:
SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the openssl extension. This is covered in [the troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score -1):

Enable access to that account [Unlock account](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)
Google disables it by default.